# Bamboo global job or stage

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

Long story short.

I have many Bamboo plans (100's) that use equal job and tasks.

When needed to add or change a task to all the plans, I need to do it Manually in each plan, which is not very efficient.

Is there something like a global job or stage that multiple plans can use?

Is there any other way you can mass update 100's of bamboo plans?

Thanks

Comment: Yes its frustrating. If you can define a single plan and then parameterise it using variables for each of your variations / branches / environments it makes it a little easier.